# Prove radius chord theorem without using congruent traingles

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, alternative-proof

Suppose that $P(a,b)$ and $Q(c,d)$ are two points on the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, and let $M$ be
the midpoint of chord $PQ$. (Without using congruent triangles), prove that $OM$ is perpendicular
to $PQ$. (Here $O$ is the origin, which is the centre of the circle).

Im not sure where to begin with this problem. I was thinking of trying to prove that the product of the slopes is $-1$, though as $P$ and $Q$ may have any coordinates on the unit circle, I'm not sure whether that is the right approach.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Math.SE.
Please avoid using block capitals - it is understood as shouting.
Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Sorry for that Jessica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the midpoint is:
$$
M\left( \frac{c + a}{2}, \frac{d + b}{2} \right)
$$

So the slopes of $OM$ and $PQ$ are, respectively:
$$
\frac{d + b}{c + a} \qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{d - b}{c - a}
$$
Multiplying these together yields:
$$
\frac{d^2 - b^2}{c^2 - a^2}
$$
Now recall that $P$ and $Q$ are on the unit circle. So we may substitute both points into the equation of the unit circle to obtain:
$$
a^2 + b^2 = 1 = c^2 + d^2
$$
Rearranging, notice that:
$$
d^2 - b^2 = a^2 - c^2 = -(c^2 - a^2) \iff \frac{d^2 - b^2}{c^2 - a^2} = -1
$$
as desired.

Comment: thank you very much for the easy to follow solution Adriano

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with vectors, they're the way to go - and we, as a nice bonus, incidentally prove the same thing about the sphere. Letting $\overrightarrow{P}$ and $\overrightarrow{Q}$ be the vectors to those points from the origin, we note that, being on the unit circle, their magnitude is $1$, and thus, using the dot product
$$\overrightarrow{P}\cdot \overrightarrow{P}=\overrightarrow{Q}\cdot\overrightarrow{Q}=1$$
Further, note that $\overrightarrow{M}=\frac{1}2(\overrightarrow{P}+\overrightarrow{Q})$, being the midpoint, and is also a vector parallel the line $OM$. Moreover, a vector parallel the line $PQ$ is $\overrightarrow{P}-\overrightarrow{Q}$. For these to be perpendicular, their dot product must be zero:
$$\frac{1}{2}(\overrightarrow{P}+\overrightarrow{Q})\cdot(\overrightarrow{P}-\overrightarrow{Q})=\frac{1}2(\overrightarrow{P}\cdot\overrightarrow{P}-\overrightarrow{Q}\cdot\overrightarrow{Q})=\frac{1}2(1-1)=0.$$
Thus, $OM$ and $PQ$ are orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you for that Meelo. I will keep that in mind though we have not been using the dot product in our geometry class so I think there may be another way that I'm supposed to looking for to solve/write this proof.